# elastic search wont return field value in result although it is declared as "store"="yes"

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to index specific document with the following mapping

```
{
   "session": { "_source": {
         "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {          
         "sessionId": {
            "type": "string"
         },
         "start": {
            "type": "date"
         },
         "text": {
            "type": "string"
            , "store": "yes"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

when searching for text

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "text": {
                  "session.text": "something"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

i do get results but session.text value wont stored in the results

Answer (score 0):

When you disable `_source` you need to explicitly state what fields you want, or specify `*` to get them all.

This is documented here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html

In your case, you want to specify `"fields": ["text"]` in your search.